# Grafana add my custom contact point type integration

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

Good afternoon. The webhook channel doesn't suit me and I want to make my own. But I can’t find information about creating my own channels. only plugins. tell me how to add my notification channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think customization of notification channels is supported.

I believe that in cases your target cannot be fully integrated using webhook, you are expected to create your own facade service, that will be receiving request from webhooks, and will be relaying needed information into final service in needed format (or with additional fields).